# Game theory reference for a beginner

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, book-recommendation

I need to use game theory to model interaction in a network. What are some books or lectures that a beginner in game theory could use to   understand the theory well?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will read it

Comment: @learn In what context? What is your background? Without providing details, you cannot expect helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to model game theoretic interactions in a network, I would strongly recommend [Social and Economic Networks, by Mathew Jackson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691148201). It might not exactly be a beginner's book but it has the advantage of addressing both topics in conjunction (Jackson now studies networks but is also a game theorist).

Another advantage is that there is a coursera MOOC linked to the book : https://www.coursera.org/course/networksonline.

Answer (score 0):

J. N. Webb, *[Game theory: Decisions, interaction and evolution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1846284236)*. London. Springer, 2007.